# Google Maps V2 Empty map on Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps API V2 in my Android application. As you can see in screenshot I have FragmentPager and there is a fragment which include google maps v2. On the device Galaxy Note 2 i have problem with displaying map content. On other devices  maps works without any problem and displays added markers and lines. As you can see that it displays only background image of my activity. There is an other issue that the map content is shown only behind of map buttons.

Any idea about solution?

Thanks.

[image: Galaxy Note 2 maps v2 Problem]

Answer (score 0):

This issues occurred because you used fragment pager and you can not move map fragment. I got similar issue in my app. So if you want to use pager, only way is to use Map v1.

Comment: I think this is not the main reason because map works without any problem on other devices. I tested this issue on 7 different device 2 of them was note 2 and only note 2 phablets make problem.